# Parallel Issue: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I have this simple code:

```
 Parallel.Invoke(
                        () => picturebox_1.Refresh(),
                    () => picturebox_2.Refresh());
```

and I'm getting this:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

How can I resolve this issue? I just want to run the refresh in parallel, the refresh method runs the Paint Event which has code to render an image...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must invoke using the UI thread, you cannot update the UI on a thread that you created, you must use the forms invoke method or the controls...

Comment: As a result of this ui operations can'nt be parallized, because the UI only runs in one thread.
Why do you want to parallelize the refresh ?

Comment: The reason I would like to parallelize the refresh is because I could refresh both controls at the same time instead of one after the other.. I think I can gain some performance by doing this?